# Moving column descriptions above the textbox

Tags: sharepoint-designer

If anyone here has a solution that they can share on how to move the column description from the bottom to above the controls whether they are multiple text lines, single text fields, radio buttons and so on.

I have been  using Sharepoint Designer 2013 to add the scripts or via the IE by editing the `newform.aspx` then adding a script editor webpart to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as possible should be done client-side, so on prem or online should not matter. I'm presuming you have an otherwise out of the box form and not having to deal with any weird custom templates.

It took me ages to realize I could do this with only a little jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/JS/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td.ms-formbody').each(function(){
        var theDescrip = $(this).contents('span.ms-metadata');
        $(this).prepend(theDescrip);
        theDescrip.after("<br/>");
    });
});
</script>
```

That is it. If anyone has some tweaks to suggest, please do.

While you could add a script editor to the page and paste this in there, I prefer to keep all my scripts in a document library and put in a content editor which references it for content (don't forget to set chrome to none on the CEWP).
I usually add in some CSS to make it larger while hiding the actual field label - use short simple field names to make it easy on yourself, while putting the more verbose labeling in the description, then add this little script to the page (I have another script to overwrite the built-in label if I prefer to put it in that form table column).

Comment: It worked. I saved the js in a document library and used a script editor to copy and paste the jquery. Thank you so much. Now, I tried to add a line break after the message but it is not working. Here is the code var theDescrip = $(this).contents('span.ms-metadata');
        $(this).prepend(theDescrip ) + '<br/>'; What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've edited the script to add in a break. the prepend line adds 'theDescrip' as the first child element under 'this' - it isnt a string you can append to like that.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me so much time. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a CSS approach - at least it worked with Person fields, you may adopt for other fields too.
The `nth-child` is very useful. In the case of person field, the description is the third row of a table with class `.ms-usereditor`. So with this code:

```
.ms-usereditor tr:nth-child(3) {display:none}
```

I have hidden all descriptions in the person fields of the form